# background image min width and positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I have two images in the background of my html doc. One positioned top right and the other bottom left.

On a mobile device the top right image does not appear top right, it appears top and about 3/4 of the way to the right. I've fiddled with min-width but no joy. Can anyone spot the issues in my code?

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/bktopright.png"), url("images/bkbottomleft.png");
    background-position: right top, left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1150px;
}
```

As I'm unsure of which part of the html or css text is causing the issue the link to the site is here if anyone has time to check it on a mobile device: http://tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

How can I ensure that the background image stays top RIGHT on a mobile/table

Comment: have you tried background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: If you have a separate mobile version, then it will be difficult for us to debug. Can you post the mobile version here?

Also, which devices are you testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, if the website you have on mobile is similar to the one you posted here, then I guess the problem is because you're using huge images. ( 1196 × 788 px )

Comment: thanks for advice on image size. I've managed to fix my immediate issue meantime and am planning a mobile site in near future.